# c# Run python script and read output lead to

Tags: c#, process

I want to run python script but my problem is that i get all the output at once at the end and not line by line (my script print the time 10 times and sleep for 1 second after each time).

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string cmd = @"C:\test.py";
    string pythonPath = @"C:\python.exe";

    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = pythonPath;//cmd is full path to python.exe
    start.Arguments = cmd;//args is path to .py file and any cmd line args
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                Console.Write(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
string cmd = @"C:\test.py";
        string pythonPath = @"C:\Python37\python.exe";

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();

    private static void OutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
```

**Python script**

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

count = 0
while count < 3:
    print(datetime.now())
    time.sleep(1)
    count += 1

print('DONE')
```

Comment: You can subscribe to event `OutputDataReceived` to read the output asynchronously. Read it about `OutputDataReceived` at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: See my update, i am still see all my output only at the end

Comment: I also add my python script, maybe the problem is in the script ? (refresh needed ?)

Comment: Suggestion comment: You could use NrobotServer to run robot framework with Csharp, You could write keywords in .net and execute them in robot framework.

Comment: What this NrobotServer  ?